# Jenkins trigger Job on multiple branch changes

Tags: git, jenkins, build

I want to build a Jenkins job when a change was done (merged) in multiple branches.

What I tried was to configure "Source Code Management" with GIT,

Branch Specifier: `*/release/*, */hotfix/*, */dev` but it don't want to build.

For build trigger I use "pull scm"

Does anyone know how I can implemnt this

Comment: did you get around this? I have the same question

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind about wildcards (*) that

> The syntax is of the form: REPOSITORYNAME/BRANCH. In addition, BRANCH is recognized as a shorthand of */BRANCH, * is recognized as a wildcard, and ** is recognized as wildcard that includes the separator '/'. Therefore, origin/branches* would match origin/branches-foo but not origin/branches/foo, while origin/branches** would match both origin/branches-foo and origin/branches/foo.

Try to use regular expression as branch specifier

```
:(release|hotfix|dev)
```

See documentation for details:

> The syntax is of the form: :regexp. Regular expression syntax in branches to build will only build those branches whose names match the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Branch specifier to match multiple branches with wildcard (Regular expression)

```
:(.*feature\/.*|.*release\/.*)
```

This would match: `origin/feature/...` or `origin/release/...`